# How to install a tawk chat in my existing laravel website already hosted in my cpanel

Tags: laravel, tawk.to

Please I have the same problem can integrate tawk chat on my existing laravel website in cpanel , I need your support can anyone explain to me the step by step I added the code in app.blade but still not working , I can't find main.blade in my views

Comment: what was the error is

Comment: My website is a script built with laravel 5.8 I have tried adding the widget to my app.blade , but it is not working , it is displaying no error , I will really appreciate a detailed step by step toturial on how to integrate this on my already hosted website in cpanel

Comment: you cant you should copy it from cpanel to localhost then install new package then update it to cpanel again there is no other way